# Synology NAS Mapped Drive not Available Until Accessed by User

Tags: network-shares, nas, windows-server-2019

I am using Synology Assistant to map a Synology NAS to my Windows Server 2019. The issue I am facing is that the drive is inaccessible to my backup scripts after a reboot until I log in myself and start browsing the contents of the network drive.

To further the point, in Explorer, the drive icon is displaying as red as if disconnected/unavailable, but it will allow you to access it when you double-click it. This is when the drive is now accessible to my scripts.

I was originally using the `net use PATH /persistent:yes` command in a script but this turned out to be less reliable than using the software from Synology (even though this still isn't reliable).

Is there a way to keep the drive mapped and accessible to any software/scripts after a reboot?

Comment: The problem is that the network drive is restored before the network is accessible, resulting in a red cross. If you ensure that the backup script runs after network accessibility is established, and you use ip or hostname directly in your script rather than a network drive, all should work well. The red cross in explorer will remain, but you can even remove that network drive, and the script will still work. Alternatively, include in your script `net use PATH` to refresh the connection. If there is network connectivity available as the script runs, the problem is solved.

Comment: You can also go about solving this problem in a different way: ensuring that network connectivity is restored faster. For example, don't rely on DHCP but set static ip addresses, use fast network switches etc...

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for your reply, that makes sense. I will give that a go! 

The NAS is already on a static address and connected through a Netgear GS724T switch so I don't think the problem lies there. Thanks for the advice though.

I'll update this comment thread with the outcome.

Comment: I was talking about the Windows Server 2019. If that instance is using DHCP, it has a delay before getting an IP address which usually causes these kinds of problems

Comment: Oh I see, that is also static. It looks to be working now, it turns out I had left my original ```net use``` script enabled in Task Scheduler. I believe that was causing some issues.

Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. I'll take note of the network being accessible before I map drives - that may save me a few headaches in the future :)

Comment: :) you're welcome. I'll write you an answer so you can accept something and others know you no longer need any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the network drive is restored before the network is accessible, resulting in a red cross. If you ensure that the backup script runs after network accessibility is established, and you use ip or hostname directly in your script rather than a network drive, all should work well.

The red cross in explorer will remain, but you can even remove that network drive, and the script will still work. Alternatively, include in your script net use PATH to refresh the connection. If there is network connectivity available as the script runs, the problem is solved.

You can also go about solving this problem in a different way: ensuring that network connectivity is restored faster. For example, don't rely on DHCP but set static ip addresses, use fast network switches etc.